# Finding a median in a union of sets given as sorted arrays

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity

You are given $k$ sorted arrays $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$, each containing $n$ elements.

> **How fast can you compute the median of $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_k$ ?**

---

I have a solution running in $\Theta(k\log k\log n)$, but this seems rather inefficient if $k=\Omega(2^\frac{n}{\log n})$, as we can always ignore the order, think of it as a unsorted array of $nk$ elements, and solve it in $O(nk)$ time.

> Assuming $k=\omega(1)$ (hence the fact the arrays are sorted give us some information), is there a sub-linear median finding algorithm (regardless of the ratio between $k$ and $n$)?
>
> Assuming $k=\text{poly}( n)$, can we beat $O(k\log k\log n)$?
>
> **Can we prove a lower bound for the problem (maybe $\Omega(k\log n)$?)?**

Comment: Perhaps you would like to ask that on cstheory.

Comment: Although this question is on-topic on [cs.se], I am migrating it to [cstheory.se] at the asker's request.

Comment: See [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20944/select-in-union-of-sorted-arrays-already-known/).